# Qemu emulator arm for tegra2

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, embedded-linux, qemu

I have Toradex Colibri t20 embedded board  Linux image (U boot,kernel,roofs). Colibri t20 is based on tegra2 arm-cortex-a9 processor. I want to run this Linux kernel in Qemu emulator.How can i boot with qemu?

Answer (score 0):

qemu-system-arm can run u-boot and kernel SW, only when it has support for the board that those SW were configured/built for.

ARM's versatilepb and vexpress-a9 are supported. There are good tutorials out there for using those boards, [Balau on kernel](http://balau82.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/compile-linux-kernel-3-2-for-arm-and-emulate-with-qemu/), also [Kumar](http://www.linuxforu.com/2011/06/qemu-for-embedded-systems-development-part-1/)

Bare metal simulation is less ambitious. There, roughly speaking, QEMU only has to emulate the processor. Check out [Balau on bare metal](http://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/hello-world-for-bare-metal-arm-using-qemu/). Quick search shows maybe there is support in progress for [Tegra2](http://wiki.qemu.org/Features/Tegra2).

I'd suggest installing current packages on your host, see what machines and cpus are supported. Not sure of the following syntax detail, but something like
qemu-system-arm -M ?
is the way to get the list of supported machines.

Comment: Actual syntax for supported CPUs is `qemu-arm-static -cpu help` ;)
At least for *Qemu 1.5.0*.